# Подскажите, какие знаки препинания здесь нужны?

Tags: пунктуация

*Умеренный торг — настоятельная просьба к тем кто будет предлагать цену значительно ниже заявленной, не беспокоить!*

Какие знаки препинания здесь нужны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение составлено неудачно, расставлять знаки препинания в нем **не имеет смысла**.

К примеру, из сочетания ***просьба не беспокоить*** инфинитив удален в конец предложения, а это связь *примыкание*, которую грамматически сложно проследить.

Вариант редактирования: ***Торг умеренный,  настоятельная просьба не предлагать цену значительно ниже заявленной!***

**То же содержание** в простой и корректной форме.

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает запятой перед *кто:*

> *Умеренный торг — настоятельная просьба к тем, кто будет предлагать цену значительно ниже заявленной, не беспокоить!*